# Xamarin iOS Login Flow with Auth0

Tags: ios, xamarin, login-control, viewwillappear, auth0

I'm getting weird behavior in my application where the user is prompted with my login screen when I'm using Auth0.  I store my token using Auth0's Account feature.  I check to see if the token exists and if the token is null, prompt user with Login Screen or go to the main loading page of my app.  I have this check on ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear methods and it works fine most of the time but then there's a few instances where the user is prompt with my login.  I only want the user to login once and never be prompted again unless they log out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I think for some reason ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear is not firing in certain cases because when I do get that login prompt, I kill the app in the background and restart the app and the login flow runs smoothly proving to me that my token was never null but it just didn't fire.